# Convert (System.Data.SqlClient) to Entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to run multi select with one trying ,

I find one way with SqlCommand and it works, but what I looking is a way with entity , please help me for finding a way with entity or convert this code to what I want .

```
string commandText = @"SELECT Id, ContactId
FROM dbo.Subscriptions;

SELECT Id, [Name]
FROM dbo.Contacts;";


List<Subscription> subscriptions = new List<Subscription>();
List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();

using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=server;Database=database;Integrated Security=true;"))
using (SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, dbConnection))
{
    dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    dbConnection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        subscriptions.Add(
            new Subscription()
            {
                Id = (int)reader["Id"],
                ContactId = (int)reader["ContactId"]
            });
    }

    reader.NextResult();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        contacts.Add(
            new Contact()
            {
                Id = (int)reader["Id"],
                Name = (string)reader["Name"]
            });
    }

    dbConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *way with entity* ? Are you using Entity framework as I can see it tagged?

Comment: Dapper has exactly the feature you want (Selecting from multiple tables and mapping each into objects) . You can check it out here: https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#multiple-results

Comment: @user3185569 yes , my project is with entity , but what I find on internet all is about sql command :(

Comment: @user3185569 I checking, it seems to be good , thanks

Comment: You'll need to install Dapper from Nuget in order to use that.

Comment: There is no good way with standard EF. But you might consider [EnitityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) package - [Future Queries](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Future-Queries)

Comment: @Mohi there is no such thing as "multi-select". What you ask is called batching. It's not available out of the box but the `EntityFramework.Extended` package allows you to batch and execute multiple requests.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so am I must to use only stored-procedures right ?

Comment: Stored procedures have nothing to do with batching multiple *client* statements and executing them at once to avoid roundtrips. Check EntityFramework.Extended and what it calls future queries. You can create multiple future queries which are executed together when you try to enumerate one of them.

Comment: BTW *why* do you want to execute multiple SELECT statements at once? The only valid reason is to avoid network roundtrips. Other cases (eg loading child entities) mean that you have a mapping bug - you *don't* need to load `Contacts` separately, they are loaded with `Subscriptions` if your `Subscription class has a `Contact` property

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos first thanks for your help, and second why I want it: because I have some page and one of pages contain many select(many of them return list) , so I must to call all of them once during loading data

Comment: @Mohi you wouldn't need to do that if you had relations between your entities. You could load the cases and all related objects would be lazily loaded as well. If you wanted everything to be loaded at once, you could use the `Include` statement in your LINQ query